# How to get user's email with Facebook SDK 3.1 on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm opening the facebook session with the email permission like so:

```
- (void)facebookOpenSession {
    NSArray *permissions = @[@"email"];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];
}
```

And then the important snippet of session state changed looks like:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                //error
             } else {
                 self.myFirstNameLabel.text = user.first_name;
                 self.myLastNameLabel.text = user.last_name;
                 // self.myEmailLabel.text = @"";
             }
         }];
    }
    ...
```

How do I actually extract the user's email? Is it in one of the provided variables, or do I have to make another call within the completion handler?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

FBGraphUser doesn't have the property (i'm assuming because its optional/only available if you asked for the email permission) but you should still be able to access it from the dictionary like this:

```
[user objectForKey:@"email"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check before yo ask the right permissions

```
loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
```